# Querying Encrypted Types, IUserType

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, encryption, fluent-nhibernate

As a requirement in the app, we have to keep some of the data in database as encrypted strings, so we have used the Encrypted Type, which implements NHibernate's IUserType (courtsey NHibernate Cookbook).

Now some of this includes the 'Name' of Users, which have to be kept encrypted.

Now we can't Query on Name using like operation, till we have fetched the data from database into the memory. Which is unadvisable for a large database.

Is there any way around or some other technique to implement Encrypted Types?

Help appreciated!

Comment: Ultimately used caching ....

Answer (score 0):

the only way to query encrypted values is to unecrypt them in the query prior the restriction. The other Option is to use weak encryption which supports like queries e.g.: simple character replace.